# auto-tokenize user agents strings for statistics?

Tags: string, substring, user-agent, tokenize, text-processing

We keep track of user agent strings in our website. I want to do some statistics on them, to see how many IE6 users we have ( so we know what we have to develop against), and also how many mobile users we have.

So we have log entires like this:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; FunWebProducts)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; FunWebProducts; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
```

And ideally, it would be pretty neat to see all the 'meaningful' strings, which would just mean probably strings longer than a certain length. For instance, I might like to see how many entries have `FunWebProducts` in it, or `.NET CLR`, or `.NET CLR 1.0.3705` -- but I *don't* want to see how many have a semi-colon. So I'm not necessarily looking for unique strings, but all strings, even sub-sets. So, I would want to see the count of all `Mozilla`, knowing that this includes the counts for `Mozilla/5.0` and `Mozilla/4.0`. It would be nice if there were a nested display for this, starting with the shortest strings, and working its way down. Something perhaps like

```
4,2093 Mozilla
 1,093 Mozilla/5.0
    468 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
     47 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U 
 2,398 Mozilla/4.0
```

This sounds like a computer science homework. What would this be called? Does something like this exist out there, or do I write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem, or, given your specific example above, a longest common prefix problem, which can be approached with a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

However, going from your example above, you probably don't even need to be efficient about this. Instead, simply:

1. Tokenize strings on some punctuation subset, like `[ ;/]`
2. Save each unique prefix of however many tokens, replacing the original delimiters
3. For each prefix, get a count of which records it matches and save that

Answer (score 0):

If you break it up into the major name (part before the opening paren), and then store each part separated by semicolon as a child record, you could do whatever analysis you want.  For example, store it in a relational database:

```
BrowserID   BrowserText
---------   -----------
1           Mozilla/4.0
2           Mozilla/5.0

FeatureID   FeatureText
---------   -----------
1           compatible
2           MSIE 7.0
3           Windows NT 5.1
4           FunWebProducts
5           .NET CLR 1.0.3705
6           .NET CLR 1.1.4322
7           Media Center PC 4.0
8           .NET CLR 2.0.50727
```

Then log references to browser and parts and you can do any type of analysis you want.

Comment: Tokenize on semi-colon won't do; I have strings like `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.9`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regex to parse the user agent string into its relevant component parts? The basic spec for a user agent string is '`[name]`/`[version]`' or '`[name]` `[version]`'. With that information we can use a regex like `([^\(\)\/\\;\n]+)([ ]((?=\d*\.+\d*|\d*_+\d*)[\d\.Xx_]+)|[/]([^\(\)\/; \n]+))` to get match sets where the first match in a set is the `[name]` and the second match in a set is the `[version]`. Of course, you'll have to strip the spaces and `/` from the second match in the set, or modify the regex to use lookbehind (which several regex flavors don't support, so I didn't include it here).

After you get all these tuples you can manipulate and count them however you want.